# where to set mysql first day of the week?

Tags: mysql

I've been looking for how to set the first day of the week on mysql server.I'm wondering if it's set on the application level as property setting or it should be set in queries as what i've been seeing so far on from google search.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `mode` argument with the function `WEEK(date, [mode])`

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week
- http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2009/04/13/mysql-week-function-weirdness/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the first day of the week can be changed at all in mySQL.

The [manual on `WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) says:

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

there is no mention that this order can be changed.