# DateFirst in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to set what the first day of
the week in MYSQL ? For e.g. if i say Set DateFirst = 1, the first day
of the week is set to Monday. If DateFirst = 2, then first day of the
week is set to Tuesday In MSSQL.
Any equivalent function in MySQL?

Comment: Googling `set first day of week mysql` seems to produce some good results. Always check that out first!

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to set mysql first day of the week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376822/where-to-set-mysql-first-day-of-the-week)